Grid only showing up on part of the page, when switching mid-document to a larger page size
I change paper size mid-document using KOMAoptions.
However my grid is only showing up on part of the larger page.
How can I make the grid span the ENTIRE page, even for the larger page? Thanks!
MWE:
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,headsep=10pt,letterpaper]{geometry}
\usepackage[paper=letter]{typearea}

%Put a grid in the background:
\newcommand{\mygraphpaper}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[line width=.6pt,draw=green!50] (current page.south west) grid[step=1cm] (current page.north east);
    \end{tikzpicture}}
\usepackage{background}
\backgroundsetup{contents=\mygraphpaper, opacity=0.3, scale=1,  angle=0, vshift=0.0cm, hshift=0.0cm}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{plain}
Text on single-size page, which may have a background or other features

\clearpage

\thispagestyle{empty}
\KOMAoptions{paper=17in:11in,paper=landscape,pagesize}
\recalctypearea
Text on double-size empty page. Why is the grid not extending over the whole page? Also how to number the grid lines?
\KOMAoptions{paper=letter,paper=portrait}
\recalctypearea

\clearpage

\thispagestyle{plain}
Text on single-size page, which may have a background or other features

\end{document}



IMHO you have placed the \clearpage wrong. It should be before changing the paper size. Moreover, book uses twoside as a default and you cannot add a single page with other format to a double sided document. You can only add complete sheets and therefore at least one odd + one even page. So IMHO a correct solution would be:
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,headsep=10pt,letterpaper]{geometry}% Makes not sense, because it is overwritten by the following line!!!
\usepackage[paper=letter]{typearea}

%Put a grid in the background:
\newcommand{\mygraphpaper}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[line width=.6pt,draw=green!50] (current page.south west) grid[step=1cm] (current page.north east);
    \end{tikzpicture}}
\usepackage{background}
\backgroundsetup{contents=\mygraphpaper, opacity=0.3, scale=1,  angle=0, vshift=0.0cm, hshift=0.0cm}



\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{plain}
Text on single-size page, which may have a background or other features

\cleardoublepage

\thispagestyle{empty}
\KOMAoptions{paper=17in:11in,paper=landscape,pagesize}
\recalctypearea
Text on double-size empty page. Why is the grid not extending over the whole
page? Also how to number the grid lines?

\cleardoublepage
\KOMAoptions{paper=letter,paper=portrait}
\recalctypearea

\thispagestyle{plain}
Text on single-size page, which may have a background or other features

\end{document}

This results in 5 pages:

With \documentclass[oneside]{book} it automatically results in 3 pages only:

Note: To use typearea together with geometry, you should load typearea with option usegeometry before geometry and also use \newgeometry after \recalctypearea. Instead of \recalctypearea alternatively \activateareas can be used. Also using typearea command \storeareas can make sense to store existing page layout and later using the storage macro to reactivate that stored setting can make sense. On the other hand, loading geometry and setting up margins etc. with geometry before loading typearea does not make any sense, because loading typearea always recalculates the margins with the methods of typearea. Also every \recalctypearea uses the algorithm of typearea to recalculate the margins. See the KOMA-Script manual for more information.
BTW: To see, how to correctly add a double-sized landscape page into a document without changing the margins, see my answer to question Insert landscape A3 page in A4 document with KOMA and geometry but keep margins or How the margins can generally be retained when changing the paper format within a document in the KOMA-Script wiki, which is also available in German. AFAIK, both do not need a KOMA-Script class but only KOMA-Script package typearea.

Wow perfect, and thanks for all the details!

Also is there an easy way to number the grid lines? So if I know I want to place something in a particular location I don't need to count lines from the corner of the page but I can just look at the numbers?

@dnh37 You are using TikZ, so yes, this is possible. But it would be another question. You should ask it as new question, if you cannot find an existing one, that already answers it, e.g., https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/558078/277964. Note, there are some packages, that support grid lines, e.g. eso-pic provides a configurable grid.
